# How to implement a shoelace formula into Python 2.7.8

Tags: python, geometry, centroids

Here's the image of the equation I'm using, it is a shoelace formula. I need help to point out what each variable represents and how to apply this in python script, math is not my strong-suit! From what I understand the X and Y are coordinate inputs and "A" is Area. I don't know what "i" is. The end goal is to create centroids. [image: polygon shoelace formula]

Comment: It may be helpful to include what you are trying to get at with this formula. What is your data and/or how is it stored? Are you simply trying to calculate the area of a given set of polygons? [ArcGIS uses the shoelace formula to calculate polygon areas](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/24650), so it could be as easy as loading it into a feature class if that's what you are after.

Comment: The Question is why you want to have it, as there are already centroid calculations available. And if you want to be independent from inbuilt functions you would at first need to calculate the area with your own formula.

Comment: I'd rather use a tool built into Arc, however I have to do it manually through python. That's why I'm trying to use this equation. 
Evil Genius, my data are US census tract polygons. I have area defined as a variable, the polygon data from which the coordinates come from is a shapefile. This is what I want to generate centroids from.

Comment: Well ok. "i" is just the number of the coordinates starting from the first x and y value. For example (x1+x2)(x1y2-x2y1). The sigma sign says that all the coordinate calculations are going to be added. "N" are the number of sides of the polygon as far as i know. And i hope you understand more from python than from math ;) otherwise it will be difficult to get a performant algorithm.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense, and I hope so too. I understand how I would code the parentheses part of the formula, but the summation with the "N-1" and "i=0" is lost to me, I don't really know where to start. I think that the "N-1" is to account for the fact that python begins counting from 0 where the polygon list starts from 1.